# Accidentally deleted the contents of my boot manager's EFI folder. I don't have a repair disc, but computer is on. (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, uefi, dell-inspiron, boot-manager

After i had uninstalled the rEFInd boot manager, i realized that i had accidentally saved it in the same directory as my actual Windows boot manager. Because of this, the entire D:\EFI folder is now empty save for 2 BCD files. My computer is still on, and i can access everything on it, but if i turn it off, i won't be able to boot it back up. I have no recovery disk, nor do i have any means of obtaining one at the moment. Is there a way for me to restore the lost files in such a situation? I'm on an Inspiron 3583 running Windows 10 Home with UEFI, if that helps.

Comment: There are copies of the EFI files in C:\Windows\Boot\EFI.

Comment: they're shown as .mui files, what do i do with these?

Comment: See the answer given by user1686.

Comment: If they're "shown as .mui files" then you're just looking at the wrong files – those are additional data (translations to different languages, I think) and not the main file itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the `bcdboot` command to reinstall the bootloader.

Comment: it says it successfully created boot files, but now D:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi, although still listed as my boot loader, is now labeled as an invalid directory. should i change the directory of this file, and if so, to what?

Comment: Labeled as invalid directory where and how? `bcdboot` installs everything to the final place and there should be no changes needed.

Comment: when i use cd D:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi, it comes back with the message "The directory name is invalid".

Comment: But... it's a file, not a directory. It's completely normal that you cannot `cd` into a file.

Comment: oh, right sorry, i removed the file name and the command works just fine! Thank you!